# How to create Web service in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am learning how to create PHP web services. I want to create a web service which exposes an interface for client integration, it would query a database that  submits a response on SMS url, but I am stuck and I don't know how to go about it.

For client this is code I have tried:

```php
<?php 
require_once ('lib/nusoap.php'); 

$param = array( 'Name' => 'Collo); 

$client = new soapclient('http://localhost/WebServiceSOAP/server.php'); 

$response = $client->call('get_message',$param); 

if($client->fault) 
{ 
echo "FAULT: <p>Code: (".$client->faultcode."</p>"; 
echo "String: ".$client->faultstring; 
} 
else 
{ 
echo $response; 
} 
?>
```

Any guidance please, even links to tutorials will be also useful.

Comment: Hi, your question is too broad as it is now, there is no specific question and you are more or less asking us "how to do this" which isn't something we cover here on SO (most of the time).

Answer (score 0):

There are many thing to learn web services

1. restful web services best way to connect data web.
   restful parser json and xml data.
2. you should using best MVC framework in inbuilt web services library.